# Python: How to repeat every 24 hours

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Hello I got a raspberry pi that i want a script to start every 24 hours :)

It is a long code:

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
import random, time

m = PyMouse()
k = PyKeyboard()

time.sleep(10) 

#Enter the website!
m.click(10, 970)
time.sleep(0.5) 
m.click(20, 770)
time.sleep(0.5) 
m.click(280, 835)
time.sleep(15)
m.click(1100, 50)
time.sleep(0.5)
m.click(900, 50)
time.sleep(0.5)
m.click(950, 50)
time.sleep(0.5)
m.click(900, 80)
time.sleep(0.5)
m.click(900, 80)
m.click(900, 80)
m.click(900, 80)
time.sleep(1)
k.type_string('url')
time.sleep(1)
k.tap_key('\r')
#enter The website done!

#login! Mr F
print('login f')
time.sleep(60) #Vent i 60 sekunter
m.click(1450, 170)
time.sleep(30)
m.click(1450, 390)
time.sleep(0.5)
k.type_string('mail')
time.sleep(0.5)
m.click(1450, 450)
time.sleep(0.5)
k.type_string('pass')
time.sleep(0.5)
m.click(40, 540)
time.sleep(0.5)
m.click(1700, 600)
print('login f done')
#Login! Mr F! DONE!

# Now on the watch page!

#watch 1 of 8  "Mr F"(normal = )
print('Watch')
time.sleep(30)
m.move(900, 370)
time.sleep(1)
m.click(900, 370)
time.sleep(60)
m.click(1700, 390)
time.sleep(1)
m.click(1790, 125)
time.sleep(1)
m.click(1450, 270)
time.sleep(1)
m.click(1720, 360)
time.sleep(1)
#watch 1 of 8 "mr f" done!

#logout Mr F
m.click(340, 120)
time.sleep(1)
m.click(360, 660)
time.sleep(1)
#logout Mr F done

#close window
m.click(1810, 10)
#close window done</code>
```

I know the code is messy, sorry about that :/
This is will be used for a school to simulate one using the pc
Why every 24 houres? the Pi will stay on for 5 days at my school. It just have to do that every 24 hours.

How can i do that?

(sorry for bad english... it is 11:42 when i'm writing this :/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use crontab:

open terminal and type :

```
crontab -e
go to the last  and add the following:
@daily python /path/of/python/script
```

if you want to run at specific time:

```
00 16 * * * python /path/of/python/script    

# it will execute the script daily at 4pm
```

here is how it works:

```
# * * * * *  command to execute
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
# │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
# └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

learn more here:[Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)
`

Comment: No need to run crontab as root unless you need root rights. It's better to put it into crontab of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running a Linux on your Raspberry: Put your script to your crontab. E.g. by adding

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/your/script
```

This will execute the script 00:00 every day. If you need more information, check `man 5 crontab`
You can edit the crontab with `crontab -e` from command line.